# Why is `--cache-from` needed even if the desired docker image has been pulled?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I'm running into some unintuitive behavior with docker in a CI/CD system. I'm specifically trying to improve the performance of docker builds when the docker layer cache is empty.

I've found the `--cache-from` argument for the docker build command which is super useful. What I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is *why* it seems like that flag is needed if I perform a `docker pull` prior to running `docker build`.

My intuition (which is obviously wrong) tells me that `docker pull` should populate the layer cache make make the `--cache-from` argument for building unnecessary. However, I'm finding that even if I perform `docker pull` I *still* need to use the `--cache-from` flag to use the layer cache when performing builds in my CI/CD system. Why is that?

Comment: Did you find the reason? I also find it counterintuitive.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't 

Comment: My best guess is that pulling the image doesn't populate the layer cache